# OCaml regexp "any" matching, where "]" is one of the characters

Tags: regex, ocaml

I'd like to match a string containing any of the characters `"a"` through `"z"`, or `"["` or `"]"`, but nothing else. The regexp should match

```
"b"
"]abc["
"ab[c"
```

but not these

```
"2"
"(abc)"
```

I tried this:

```
let content_check(s:string):bool = 
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp "^[a-z[\]]*$") s 0;;

content_check "]abc[";;
```

and got warned that the "escape" before the "]" was illegal, although I'm pretty certain that the equivalent in, say, sed or awk would work fine.

Anyhow, I tried un-escaping the cracket, but

```
let content_check(s:string):bool = 
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp "^[a-z[]]*$") s 0;;
```

doesn't work at all, since it should match any of `a-z` or `"["`, then the first `"]"` closes the "any" selection, after which there must be any number of `"]"`s. So it *should* match

```
[abc]]]]
```

but not

```
]]]abc[
```

In practice, that's not what happens at all; I get the following:

```
#   let content_check(s:string):bool = 
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp "^[a-zA-Z[]]*$") s 0;;

content_check "]abc[";;
content_check "[abc]]]";;
content_check "]abc[";;

  val content_check : string -> bool = <fun>
#   - : bool = false
# - : bool = false
# - : bool = false
```

Can anyone explain/suggest an alternative?

@Tim Pietzker's suggestion sounded really good, but appears not to work:

```
# #load "str.cma" ;; 
let content_check(s:string):bool = 
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp "^[a-z[\\]]*$") s 0;;

content_check "]abc[";;
#   val content_check : string -> bool = <fun>
#   - : bool = false
#
```

nor does it work when I double-escape the "[" in the pattern, just in case. :(

Indeed, here's a MWE:

```
#load "str.cma" ;; 
let content_check(s:string):bool = 
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp "[\\]]") s 0;;

content_check "]";; (* should be true *)
```

Comment: Try as  `^[a-z\[\]]+$`

Comment: Nice idea, but that doesn't work, alas.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to really answer your question, but it will solve your problem. With the [re](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re) library:

```
let re_set = Re.(rep (* "rep" is the star *) @@ alt [
    rg 'a' 'z' ; (* the range from a to z *)
    set "[]" ; (* the set composed of [ and ] *)
  ])

(* version that matches the whole text *)
let re = Re.(compile @@
    seq [ start ; re_set ; stop ])

let content_check s =
  Printf.printf "%s : %b\n" s (Re.execp re s)

let () =
  List.iter content_check [
    "]abc[" ;
    "[abc]]]" ;
    "]abc[" ;
    "]abc[" ;
    "abc@#"
  ]
```

As you noticed, `str` from the stdlib is akward, to put it midly. `re` is a very good alternative, and it comes with various regexp syntax *and* combinators (which I tend to use, because I think it's easier to use than regexp syntax).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into "re" (or perhaps just get through the current task and forget it, since Ocaml really doesn't seem to be the right language for what I'm trying to do -- awk might work a good deal better!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. (But perhaps the designers of Str weren't so clever either.)

From the "Str" documentation: "To include a ] character in a set, make it the first character in the set."

With this, it's not so clear how to search for "anything except a ]", since you'd have to place the "^" in front of it. Sigh.

:(

Comment: no, the author is right, the idiom to include square bracket in a character set is to put the closing one right after the open one and the open one right before the closing one. so `[][]` this char set will match open and closing bracket. if you mean the opposite, `[^][]` does the work. you can check with sed, i think it's the same in other systems too

Comment: The problem with that solution is when you want to search for [, ], and -, since putting [ just before the end removes the only spot where - can go. Also: I agree that [^[] works to find anything-but-[, but the documentation says that to include [ in a set, you must make it the first character, while "^" is actually the first character in this set (albeit one with a special meaning). So the doc is, at best, written a little unclearly.